# Access value in JSON dictionary returned from Stripe API in Meteor

Tags: javascript, json, meteor, stripe-connect

the Stripe API is returning me a JSON dictionary (whatever that is) when the Stripe oAuth process fails. I have stored that as a variable, but I cannot access the value in side it "error_description". [Here is a link to the relevant Stripe docs](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/reference#get-authorize-errors)

Not sure if it makes a difference, but this is in a Meteor app in a server side method.

I have the following stored as a variable called "error". This is what I get when I console.log(error);

```
{ [Error: failed [400] {   "error": "invalid_grant",   "error_description": "Authorization code does not exist: ac_7z4pnJ8ee71yJNxguV6wiINIf10fgl6j" }] stack: [Getter] }
```

My question is: How can I access the "error_description"?

It doesn't seem to work when I write

```
var newError = error.error_description
```

If anyone can help me get the error_description that would be awesome, thanks!

**Update**
Adding .message removed part of the response, but I still can't JSON.parse it or access the error_description

var error = error.message results in

```
failed [400] {   "error": "invalid_grant",   "error_description": "Authorization code does not exist: ac_7z4pnJ8ee71yJNxguV6wiINIf10fgl6j" }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have received an [error object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error).

You should be able to use:

```
 error.message
```

That part seems to be a JSON string, but it is prefixed with text like "failed [400] ", which is not part of the JSON that follows. So you should strip that first part to get the JSON string, like this:

```
 var json = /(\{.+)/.exec(error.message)[1]; // strip prefix

 var errorObj = JSON.parse(json);

 console.log(errorObj.error_description);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. When I do that, I get this error:

'Exception while invoking method 'stripeAuth' SyntaxError: Unexpected token E
I20160227-12:34:12.414(0)?     at Object.parse (native)
I20160227-12:34:12.414(0)?     at [object Object].Meteor.methods.stripeAuth (server/stripe/methods/stripe-connect-authenticate.js:18:20)'

Comment: There is more but I think the top 3 lines tell the story

Comment: Thanks, still not quite working but that did change something. Updated my original question at the bottom so you can see

Comment: Still no luck, same error as before about unexpected token at Object.parse

Why the hell isn't stripe just returning a standard JSON? Also, thanks for your time I really appreciate it

Comment: `console.log` output is not really easy to understand. Could you instead use `console.log(JSON.stringify(error.message))` and tell me what you get?

Comment: This is what i get when I run that:




"failed [400] {   \"error\": \"invalid_grant\",   \"error_description\": \"Authorization code does not exist: ac_7z4pnJ8ee71yJNxguV6wiINIf10fgl6j\" }"

Comment: Ok, it seems that this "failed [400] " is really there in the response, but should not. It is not JSON. It seems to give the length of the rest of the string. I propose code to remove that prefix. See updated answer.

Comment: Unfortunately it still isn't working. This isn't worth wasting your time or mine on, I will just use a generic error message for now and contact Stripe to ask them why they aren't returning a normal JSON object.

Thanks for all your help

Comment: One last attempt: I corrected the placement of opening bracket in regular expression for stripping the JSON. I would appreciate if you can just give that a try.

Comment: You're welcome. BTW: you can express your appreciation by upvoting :)

Comment: Upvoited everything. Massively appreciate your help. Thank you